# Title missing in list

Tags: list, item, copy

Working in SP 2013 I created a tracking log for tasks and when the task is marked "Complete" it is first copied to an archive folder and then deleted from the main list.  The new item appears in the archive list, but the 'Title' field shows "No Title".  This also happens in the 4-number category field - no number appears.  Both fields are present in the main working list.  Why didn't the fields' information copy over with the rest of the information? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How code you use for copying?

I think that you must create a new record in Archive list from the Original record and after this delete it, so you should do something like
* Create new item in Archive list
* Get ID of new item
* Set attributes to new item
* ItemUpdate
* Delete original item.

Comment: I have a WF where if the 4-number category field falls between a certain range, then it copies that record into the appropriate list.  It used to copy all information over, but now for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: Check WF definition and republish it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's still showing the Title field as "no title" and blank in the category field.

Comment: So check variable which you fill from original record's Title, if it work correctly. if you have title value in variable, use it for fill to new record.

Comment: did it help to You?